# Any way to use a method on a template class (when you have a pointer of a base class) when not knowing the used template type

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have this :

```
class A 
{
    virtual int Method2(){/*...*/}
};

template<typename T>
class B<T> : public A
{
public :
    virtual int Method1(){/*...*/}
    virtual int Method2(){/*...*/}
};
```

Is it possible to do something similar to this (this does not work of course...) ?

```
A* a = ...;

B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);

b->Method1();
```

Thanks

Comment: remember that templates are not types or functions, they are "models" for the compiler to create types or functions. As such, you cannot use a "bare" template in lieu of a type or function, you always have to use a full instance of the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What people normally do is have an intermediary class.

```
class A { virtual ~A() {} };
class B : public A { virtual void method(); }
template<typename T> class C : public B {
    void method() { ... }
};

A* a = new C<int>();
if(B* b = dynamic_cast<B>(a)) {
    b->method();
}
```

This is known as type erasure. However, in this system, A doesn't really serve much purpose.

Comment: Ok, that what I used, but I wondered if there was a simpler way to do it,  in my case this (inserting intermediary class) involves modification of many classes...

Comment: Then what is the point of class A? You can completely remove it, and leave just class B.

Comment: @VJo : Class A should actually have implemented methods, as in my example code.  Here it is in its basic form for simplicity...

Comment: @VJo: I assume that other classes inherit from A, else the OP would have just moved method1 there.

Comment: @smichaud This answer has a base class with no methods at all (except for destructor). IMO that base class should be completely removed.

Comment: @DeadMG "Type erasure" as you call it is an awful practice, which serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you meant:

```
template<typename T>
class B { and the rest of it }
```

Then B isn't a class, so there's no such thing as a `B*`. Unless your code is inside the class template B, that is, in which case `B` refers to what outsiders call `B<T>` for some type T.

The contents of the `...` is quite important too. This is fine:

```
A *a = new B<int>();
B<int> *b = static_cast<B<int>*>(a);
b->Method1();
```

Finally, you can only `dynamic_cast` if the classes have virtual functions, which in your example they don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A 
{
    //...
};

template <class T>  //you missed this line
class B : public A  //note the public keyword
{
public :
    int Method1(){/*...*/}
};
```

Now you can use

```
A* a = new B<char>;

B<char>* b = dynamic_cast<B<char>*>(a);

b->Method1();
```

Note that B is not a class, it's aclass template. So you need to provide template arguments

Answer (score 0):

No, because `B` is not a complete type.  You can't get a pointer to a `B` because there's no such thing as a `B`.

It looks like you're trying to use templates to accomplish run-time polymorphism.  Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

B has to have a complete type, that is, B<Something>. Then you can do it as with a normal class, but you cannot do it with the class alone without the type parameter.